# Unsure of for loop

Tags: python, string, function

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. When I enter a DNA sequence that contains a bad variable (like Z) I keep getting a return True. Can someone point out why?

Thanks

```
def is_valid_sequence(dna):
    """ (str) -> bool

    >>> is_valid_sequence('ATCG')
    True
    >>> is_valid_sequence('AZT')
    False
    >>> is_valid_sequence('atcg')
    False

    Returns a boolean result based on whether dna is a valid
    dna sequence.
    """



    for char in dna:
        if char in "TCGA":
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're returning on the first iteration of the loop: `return` *ends* the function, and all paths in the body of your loop contain a `return`. You probably want

```
for char in dna:
    if char not in 'TCGA':
        return False
return True
```

Or, more Pythonically:

```
return all(char in 'TCGA' for char in dna)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in my original code the result was based on the first letter in the string essentially? That determined the return result of the for loop?

Comment: @Zack: Exactly. Both your `if` and your `else` led to a `return` statement which would immediately terminate the function with the specified return value.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you take char one by one and return True if it is in "TCGA". So if the first char is in "TCGA" it would return True and will stop execution. You should do something like this:

```
for char in dna:
    if char not in "TCGA":
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You're always returning after testing the first character. Keep testing until you reach a bad character, don't return `True` until you've tested the whole string.